# ASP.NET APP Works Only When The Query Is Executed From The Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I have an application that queries a database hosted on a windows 2003 server.  IIS appears to works fine because other applications work ok.

However, when I try to access this application from a remote machine I get an error.

I realized that the application starts working on the remote PCs when I execute a query from the server. Then the application works remotely.

Why is this happening? Is this a certificate problem? Does anybody have a clue?

Here is the exception

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   BH.Sysnet.DBHelper.SetSqlExceptionMessage(StringBuilder msg, Exception ex) +741
   BH.Sysnet.DBHelper.CreateDbException(DB db, Exception ex) +68
   BH.Sysnet.DB.ExecuteReturnDS(String sql, CommandType statementType, String nombreDataTable, DataSet ds) +206
   BH.Sysnet.DB.ExecuteReturnDS(String sql, String nombreDataTable, DataSet ds) +15
   BH.Sysnet.DB.ExecuteReturnDS(String sql, String nombreDataTable) +12
   BH.Sysnet.DB.ExecuteReturnDS(String sql) +16
   BH.GIDEWS.Pages.Log.Buscar() +1717
   BH.GIDEWS.Pages.Log.btnBuscar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: When you access the application 'locally' are you doing so through your development environment? What kind of authentication are your running on your database server (what kind of database server?)

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This looks like the server cant get the values from the Database

Comment: @Cos Callis: the database server is MicrosoftSQL and here they have a class to work with the databases authentications but i dont think that the class its failing to authenticate, because as i said they use the same class for all the applications

Comment: @ShinyDarkStone _IF_ the connection model is integrated security and _IF_ you are accessing the application _locally_ through your development environment you could be presenting different credentials. As a local user you would be presenting your own windows credentials, where as the remote access would be using the IIS process credentials. Yes there are some "_IFs_" here, but it could account for your issue.

Comment: yes, that was what i was thinking, but i have configured the virtual directory security with a common user, the credentials are still diferent?

Comment: The virtual directory security is irrelevant in this issue. You want to look at connection string being served to the connection object. If the security is  set to 'integrated' then it is using your credentials locally and the Credentials that IIS is running under remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Check you can see the appropriate port on the server from the remote machine - could this be a firewall configuration issue?

Next, confirm that you are able to connect to the database from the remote machine. Use whatever SQL command prompt tool is available, and see what happens... The idea here is to rule out Permissions issues - are you allowed to connect from the remote machine?

If you're able to do so, can you post the code that is failing, together with the output you are getting (full exception text if available...)

Martin.

Comment: to the first question, yes i can see the appropiate ports, and no, it cant be the firewall because its a development server, it have all the security options off so we can test everything.
I can connect to the database i use the. i can connect, let me see if i can get where its failing.
i will update now the full exception